# canvas page - reposition on page beginning onload

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a canvas page with a form. When the user submits the form, he gets redirected to another page that displays the selection.

The problem is that the 1st page has a height of 3000px and the 2nd page is just 400px tall.

Facebook does not recognize that..
When the user submits the form and the second page gets loaded inside the canvas, the browser scrollbar position and total page height stay at the previous page.

In this way when displaying the 2nd page, the user sees just blank space unless he scrolls manually to the top.

Is there an api call to go on the top of the page?

Or should I use something like: body onload go to (0,0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, the facebook java sdk contains a function to do it.

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```